# activeadmin: model of parent resource page must have association with name equal to name of child resource page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, belongs-to

model RegionCountry must have association named cities (because child resource page generates controller with name CityController)

How can I customize association name?

backtrace:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `cities' for #<RegionCountry:0x0000000605f158>):
activemodel (4.0.9) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in `method_missing'
activerecord (4.0.9) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:168:in `method_missing'
inherited_resources (1.5.1) lib/inherited_resources/base_helpers.rb:184:in `end_of_association_chain'
```

app/admin/region_city.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register RegionCity, as: 'City' do
  permit_params :name, :description, :country_id
  menu false
  belongs_to :country, parent_class: RegionCountry
  navigation_menu :default
  filter :id_eq
end
```

pp/admin/region_country.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register RegionCountry, as: 'Country' do
  permit_params :name, :description
  filter :id_eq
  sidebar 'Links', only: [:show] do
    ul do
      li do
        link_to 'Cities', admin_country_cities_path(country_id: resource.id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

app/models/region_city.rb

```
class RegionCity < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :country, class_name: RegionCountry, foreign_key: :country_id

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :country, presence: true
end
```

app/models/region_country.rb

```
class RegionCountry < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :reg_cities, class_name: RegionCity, foreign_key: :country_id
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
  revision: a2cd9604c2d949f5193791045385756cee0c6865
```

but if we changed app/models/region_city.rb like this:

```
class RegionCountry < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many :cities, class_name: RegionCity, foreign_key: :country_id # this line was changed
end
```

it will work fine

here is test app that repeats an error:
https://github.com/senid231/activeadmin_test_belongs_to/tree/rename_child

Answer (score 2):

By default Inherited Resources (used by ActiveAdmin) assumes the collection
name to mirror the resource's name, which would be `ResourceCountry#cities` and
explains the undefined method error. Altering the defaults in the controller
will fix the issue:

```
ActiveAdmin.register RegionCity, as: 'City' do
  belongs_to :country, parent_class: RegionCountry

  controller do

    # Instruct inherited_resources on how to find the collection from the
    # parent resource (by default it is assumed to be `:cities`); instead
    # use `:reg_cities` as the name of the collection (from
    # `RegionCountry#reg_cities`):

    defaults collection_name: :reg_cities
  end
end
```

See Inherited Resource's documentation for [overriding defaults](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources#overwriting-defaults) for more
detail.